# Proof of Residency for Interrail as German Citizen Living in the UK

Tags: uk, residency, interrail

I live in the UK since allmost a year and would like to visit family and friends in Germany followed by an interrail trip. So I would like to get an Interrail pass as a UK resident. Eventhough I found the FAQ concerning how to prove residency

https://www.interrail.eu/en/what-my-country-residence

> Your residence can be proved with official government-issued residency papers. This must be a valid document that clearly shows that you're an official resident of the country you live in (for example, a residence card).
>
> Your proof of residence will be accepted if:
>
> - It is issued by the government.
> - It is valid for the entire duration of your Interrail trip.
> - It has an official mark or stamp from the issuing body.
> - It clearly states the issuing country.
> - It clearly states your name.
>
> Documents such as bills, rental contracts or bank statements cannot be used. Travel visas and the residency field of a passport are also not accepted as proof of residency.

I still have no Idea what kind of document I should use for this. After all as a European citizen you dont have to register here so there was really no occasion at which I could have gotten such a document. Also I can't apply for a residency card as this is only granted to non european citizens.

Does anybody has experience with this situation?

---

I contacted the WhatsApp help service from Interrail: they just repeated that I need a document that satisfies the properties listed above.

Comment: I think your (German?) passport will contain not your complete address, but your town of residence. Hopefully that would be enough.

Comment: They also specify "Travel visas and the residency field of a passport are also not accepted as proof of residency."

Comment: Have you looked at the guidance under the option ‘I'm a European citizen, but I'm also an official resident of another European country’? It says:

You can choose whether you select your country of citizenship or the country where you live as the country of residence on your Interrail Pass. If you choose your country of citizenship, your passport will serve as proof of residence. If you choose the country where you live, you must bring official proof of residence in that country.

Comment: Yes it is about what I can use as "official proof of residence"

Comment: @Florian But can’t you select your country of citizenship, and use your passport as proof of residence (ie in your country of citizenship)

Comment: @Traveller The problem is that as a German resident I could not travel through Germany.

Comment: @Florian So are you applying for an Interrail One Country Pass, not a Global Pass?

Comment: @Traveller No I want to apply for a global pass start my journey in the UK, where I live, visit Germany and then travell on to Switzerland and France and then back to the UK. But if my status is German resident I cannot visit Germany on the way.

Comment: @Florian Ok, I read the information differently - if you select Germany as your country of residence the Global Pass gives you one inbound and one outbound journey within Germany.

Comment: @Traveller but I want to have more than just one journey within Germany

Comment: Perhaps your NINO would suffice https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number? I’d contact Interrail Support for advice using their online Customer Service Form

Comment: Inter-rail also have a great whatsapp service for queries like this: +31 6 40789005

Comment: Will a Council Tax bill issued by the local authority for property tax suffice?

Comment: Would a UK issued full or provisional driving licence suffice as they would show your UK address where you reside? Provisional licence is easy to get and anyone can get it (£34 and about one or two weeks wait).

Comment: Putting on hold until OP clarifies some of the questions in the comments.

Comment: @Owain No I do not think so. I think the document needs a passport number.

Comment: @kiradotee driving licenses are explicitly listed as not valid to prove residency.

Comment: @Florian the requirements quoted in the question do not mention passport number (nor any other identification number).  Also driver's licenses are explicitly excluded as proof of *citizenship,* not as proof of residence.

Comment: You can apply for a registration document: https://www.gov.uk/apply-registration-certificate

Comment: You could file a complaint. They deserve at least some work for such discrimination. Well... buying interrail for Germany is a waste of money anyway. A Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket gets you the same with more flexibility.

Comment: Would a driving licence do? Swap your German one for a British one or get a provisional licence.

Comment: I wonder if a council tax bill would do the job?

Answer (score 6):

you can register at the German Embassy in London and get a change of residency status in your passport.

https://uk.diplo.de/uk-de/02/-pass/wohnortaenderung

It's a bit annoying, but shouldn't be a problem.

Edit: The Interrail Whatsapp customer service just confirmed that this is the only option for Uk residents.